# retrieve the non null values from a PySpark dataframe row and store this value in a new column

Tags: python, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have a PySpark dataframe which has column names which are unique_id's generated by UUID library. So I cannot query using column names. Each row in this pySpark dataframe has 1 "non null value". How do i create a new column which only has this 1 non null value? I have shared a sample below where "new_column" is the column I would like to create. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
col1    col2      col3          col4             new_column    
Null    Null       xyz           Null                    xyz
```

I tried looking at dataframe operations but i was unable to find any relevant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) on all columns

```
df = df.withColumn('new_column', F.coalesce(*df.columns))
```

---

```
+----+----+----+----+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|new_column|
+----+----+----+----+----------+
|null|null| xyz|null|       xyz|
| pqr|null|null|null|       pqr|
+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: thank you so much ! this really helps. I forgot to add one detail however. There is an "id" column which is a unique identifier. I want to ignore that column alone and coalesce the remaining columns. How do i do that?

Comment: That's easy just do: `df = df.withColumn('new_column', F.coalesce(*df.drop('id').columns))`